# VBA CODE FOR CONCATENATION

Tags: vba, excel

Hi i am currently working on vba my query is two rows with header name B_CHGCODE & ITEM CODE values needs to be concatenated and paste it in different worksheet named B_CHGCODE & ITEM CODE

Comment: Why are you shouting?

Comment: It seems you forgot to include a question in your question.

Comment: Please read [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like `sheet1!A2&sheet1!B2` if `sheet1` is the worksheet where `B_CHGCODE` and `ITEM CODE` are located?
In VBA, would be the same: use `Range` types to point to your cells in `sheet1` as well as your target cells in the other sheet. And then the concatenation is obvious with `RangeTarget.Value=RangeBChgCode.value&RangeItemCode.Value`.
I cannot go any further as I don't know how your cells are defined.. Named ranges?

Comment: yes in sheet1 B_CHGCODE  is one row heading and item code is another row heading all the below listed values should concatenate and paste it in B_CHGCODE & ITEM CODE SHEET.

Comment: Row headings are unusual. Do you mean your data are horizontal, right to their title? How is defined where they are located (a name?). How to figure out how many they are? Why is VBA required in the first place?